# Summarise area interactions based on criteria to generate new names and metrics

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets:

```
library(dplyr)

Lookup <- tibble(
      Code = c("A001", "A002", "A003", "A004", "A005", "A006", "A007", "A008"),
      Name = c("Location V", "Location G", "Location B", "Location D", "Location L", "Location X", "Location W", "Location J"),
      NoSpaces = c("LocationV", "LocationG", "LocationB", "LocationD", "LocationL", "LocationX", "LocationW", "LocationJ"))

Data <- tibble(
      Code = c("A001", "A001", "A001", "A001", "A002", "A002", "A004", "A004", "A004", "A004", "A007", "A007", "A008"),
      Name = c("Location V", "Location V", "Location V", "Location V", "Location G", "Location G", "Location D", "Location D", "Location D", "Location D", "Location W", "Location W", "Location J"), 
      NoSpaces =  c("LocationV", "LocationV", "LocationV", "LocationV", "LocationG", "LocationG", "LocationD", "LocationD", "LocationD", "LocationD", "LocationW", "LocationW", "LocationJ"), 
      AltName = c("Location V", "Place Y", "Place G", "Place B", "Place N", "Place F", "Place K", "Place W", "Location G", "Place P", "Place D", "Location W", "Place C"),
      AltNoSpaces = c("LocationV", "PlaceY", "PlaceG", "PlaceB", "PlaceN", "PlaceF", "PlaceK", "PlaceW", "LocationG", "PlaceP", "PlaceD", "LocationW", "PlaceC"),
      Number = c(0.35, 0.22, 0.23, 0.44, 0.6, 0.4, 0.32, 0.34, 0.21, 0.54, 0.11, 0.14, 1))
```

I am trying to find out if the areas in `Lookup` can be assigned an alternative name(s) using `Data`. What I would like as an output is for any area that intersects with those in `Lookup` with a number greater than 0.30 to be used to create a new name string, ordered from the highest value to the smallest. Some areas in `Lookup` are not present in `Data`, but I would like those values to be used meaning an output would look like:

```
Output <- tibble(
    Code = c("A001", "A002", "A003", "A004", "A005", "A006", "A007", "A008"),
    New_Name = c("Place B & Location V", "Place N & Place F", "Location B", "Place P, Place W & Place K", "Location L", "Location X", "Location W", "Place C"),
    Old_Name = c("Location V", "Location G", "Location B", "Location D", "Location L", "Location X", "Location W", "Location J"),
    Revised_Name_Number = c(2,2,1,3,1,1,1,1),
    Number_of_Possible_Names = c(4,2,NA,4,NA,NA,2,1),
    Revised_and_Orginal_Same = c("FALSE","FALSE",NA,"FALSE",NA,NA,"TRUE","FALSE"),
    Original_Name_in_Revised_Name = c("TRUE","FALSE",NA,"FALSE",NA,NA,"TRUE","FALSE"),
    Original_Name_Possible = c("TRUE","FALSE",NA,"FALSE",NA,NA,"TRUE","FALSE"))
```

The additional attributes I would like included are:

- Revised_Name_Number - The number of names that make up New_Name for
  each area
- Number_of_Possible_Names - The number of possible names in
  Data that could have been assigned to each area
- Revised_and_Orginal_Same - If 'Old_Name' and 'New_Name' for each area
  are the same
- Original_Name_in_Revised_Name - If the 'Old_Name' for
  each area is included as part of 'New_Name'
- Original_Name_Possible - Was 'Old_Name' a possibility for the 'New_Name' i.e. was it in `Data`
  for that area

I know this can be used to create 'New_Name' from a list of names that meet my criteria:

```
summarise(New_Name = sub("(.*)," , "\\1 &" , toString(AltName)))
```

But the only way I can achieve all of the above is with for loops and if statements. I am hoping there is a more efficient way to achieve the type of output I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the output I am after using `Lookup` and `Data` as the inputs:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

Join <- full_join(Lookup %>% select(Code, Name, NoSpaces), 
                    Data %>% select(-Name, -NoSpaces) %>% filter(is.na(Number)|Number >0.3) %>% arrange(Code,-Number),
                    by = c("Code")) %>%
            group_by(Code) %>%
            summarise(Revised_Name = sub("(.*)," , "\\1 &" , toString(AltName))) %>%
            left_join(Lookup,., by =("Code")) %>%
            mutate(Revised_Name = ifelse(Revised_Name == "NA", Name, Revised_Name),
            Revised_and_Orginal_Same = as.character(Name==Revised_Name),
            Original_Name_in_Revised_Name = as.character(ifelse(str_detect(Revised_Name, fixed(Name)), TRUE, FALSE)))
                
Data_Summary <- Data %>%
                group_by(Code) %>%
                summarise(Revised_Name_Number = as.double(sum(Number>0.3)),
                            Number_of_Possible_Names = as.double(n()),
                            Original_Name_Possible = if(any(AltNoSpaces %in% NoSpaces))"TRUE" else "FALSE")
                
Output_Data <- left_join(Join, Data_Summary, by=("Code")) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(Revised_and_Orginal_Same = ifelse(Revised_Name_Number >=0, Revised_and_Orginal_Same, NA),
            Original_Name_in_Revised_Name = ifelse(Revised_Name_Number >=0, Original_Name_in_Revised_Name, NA)) %>%
    select(Code, Revised_Name, Name, Revised_Name_Number, Number_of_Possible_Names, Revised_and_Orginal_Same, Original_Name_in_Revised_Name, Original_Name_Possible)
```